# Flutter | How to pause / unpause a widget and all its descendants?

Tags: flutter

In my Flutter app, I have a tabbar. Each tap is its own widget with lots of descendants widgets (see diagram).

In the Scaffold building the tabbar, the children are located in a [IndexedStack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IndexedStack-class.html) widget - this is super cool, since it allows the user to change tabs without losing state.

*Problem:* Since we use `IndexedStack`, the entire widget tree for inactive (i.e in background) tabs are preserved, and all animations/servercalls are executed regardless.

**Question**: Is it possible to **pause** a widget + all the widgets descendants?

Expected result: Widgets gets paused/unpaused if they are in foreground or background, preserving resources but still not losing state.

[image]

Example:

```
Scaffold(
body: IndexedStack(index: i, children: [TabA(), TabB(), TabC()], // <- How to pause/unpause TabA, TabB, TabC?
bottomNavigationBar: // Tabbar widget here
)
```

Comment: You can try visibility detector from pub.